# reinstall broken python3 in ubuntu 18.4

Tags: python-3.6

I tried to uninstall python3 in ubuntu 18.4. after that I give the broken dependencies in every install command.
I even have this problem with `'sudo apt upgrade'`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but it is not installed
           Depends: python3.6 (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not installed
 python3-keyring : Depends: python3-secretstorage but it is not installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
               Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.5) but it is not installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution command is: sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please consider explaining how this command would solve the problem.